# Countif in a row with row criteria

Tags: excel

In Excel, I have a list of golfers and their scores. I want to find a way to count how many times they scored a **4** when playing.

So in column `B`, I have a list of golfers. Then in columns `C` through `T` I have their scores. The golfers names are listed more than once. So I want a way to match their name in the list then count how many times they scored a **4** for that day.

I tried `INDEX-MATCH` and `SUMPRODUCT`, but couldn't get a proper result.
Sample data:

```
B     C D E F G H
-----------------
Brian 2 3 4 4 2 3
Greg  3 4 3 3 4 5
Eric  4 3 3 4 5 2
Greg  4 2 2 3 4 5
Eric  4 4 3 3 2 2
```

My desired solution:
With a list of players on another sheet, I want a formula that will `count` the total instances of the number **4** for each player.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a list of unique names, for example in column J, then you can use a Sumproduct like this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($C$2:$H$6=4)*($B$2:$B$6=J2))
```

[image]

The data can be on a different sheet, of course.

Comment: There it is. Perfect. I had this, but made a silly error and couldn't see it.

Comment: @otterdog2000 If this answers your question, please mark it as the answer as explained in the [Tour].